# spacing in a word javascript

Tags: javascript, html, space

I wrote this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout( function(){
        if($("#site-type").length) {
        $(".typewrite span").typed({
            strings: ["show case ", "projekt"],
            typeSpeed: 100,
            backDelay: 500,
            loop: false,
            fontcolor: "green",
            contentType: 'html', // or text
            // defaults to false for infinite loop
            loopCount: false,
      [A-Za-z']+( [A-Za-z']+)*$
        });
    }
    }, 4000);
});
}
```

I want to have space in it like this:
Hello (and here is the script typing)

Not like this:
Hello(and here is the script typing)

Comment: Where is your text? I don't see the part where you actually build your string.

Comment: Why did you paste your Regex randomly in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: try replacing `strings: ["show case ", "projekt"],` with `strings: [" ", "show case ", "projekt"],`

Comment: It works but its popping under the words, do you now what i mean?

Comment: You could also try `strings: [" show case ", " projekt"],` note the leading space.

Comment: It works with that to but "showcase and projekt" is popping under the words that are written in html :(

Comment: Now i got it! Thanx for the help